# Reading Formatted .txt File into Variables: Java

Tags: java

I Have a formatted text file called cars.txt; It's separated by tabs.

```
Name    Length  Width
truck1  18.6    8.1
suv1    17.4    7.4
coupe1  14.8    5.4
mini1   14.1    5.0
sedan1  16.4    6.1
suv2    17.5    7.3
mini2   14.3    5.2
sedan2  16.5    6.2
```

I need to read in this information so it can be used for calculations later on.
This is my current idea but I am having a hard time piecing together what I need to execute.

```
public class Class{

    public void readFileIn(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("cars.txt");

            try{
               while (sc.hasNextLine()){ 
                    if (/**something that catches strings*/){
                        method1(string1, double1, double2);
                        method2(double1, double2);
                    }


                }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
                System.out.println("File dosen't exist");
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scanner and Buffer Reader are not used very often anymore as Java provides a better way to achieve tha same result with less code.
I can see at least three possible approaches to solve your problem:

**approach 1**: if you can use at least Java 8, then I would suggest to use the  [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) libraries to [read the file as a stream of lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
Stream<String> linesStream=Files.lines("cars.txt");
```

Then depending on what you need to do, you could use either [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) that will loop on each line of the stream:

```
linesStream.forEach(e -> e.myMethod());
```

Or [Java Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) to execute the calculation that you need to. A good tutorial about Collectors can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors). You can use collectors also to separate your string etc...

**approach 2**: you can use Apache Commons libraries to achieve the same goal. In particular you could use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). For instance:

```
File carFile=new File("cars.txt");

LineIterator lineIterator=lineIterator(carFile);

for(String line : lineIterator) {

         String[] my values=StringUtils.split(line);

//do whatever you need

}
```

**approach 3**: use Jackson to transform your file into a json or a java object that you can then use for your own transformations. [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-java) is an example explaining how to convert a CSV to JSON. With a bit of digging in the Jackson documentation, you could apply it to your case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i recommend you create an `Entry` class that represents your data.

```
private class Entry {
    private String name;
    private double length;
    private double width;

    // getters and setters omitted

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

Next, create a method that takes a `String` as an arguments and is responsible for parsing a line of text to an instance of `Entry`. The regex `\\s+` matches any whitespace characters and will split your line to its individual columns. Remember that in production, `Double.valueOf` can throw an `RuntimeException` if your are not passing a valid `String`.

Finally, you can read the file, here using the Java 8 stream API. Skip the first line since it includes the column header and not actual data.

```
private void readFile() throws Exception {
    Path path = Paths.get(/* path to your file */);

    Files.readAllLines(path).stream().skip(1).map(FileReadTest::toEntry)
            .forEach(this::action);
}
```

In my example, i am just printing each entry to the console:

```
private void action(Entry entry) {
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

Resulting output:

```
Entry[name='truck1', length=18.6, width=8.1]
Entry[name='suv1', length=17.4, width=7.4]
Entry[name='coupe1', length=14.8, width=5.4]
Entry[name='mini1', length=14.1, width=5.0]
Entry[name='sedan1', length=16.4, width=6.1]
Entry[name='suv2', length=17.5, width=7.3]
Entry[name='mini2', length=14.3, width=5.2]
Entry[name='sedan2', length=16.5, width=6.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to properly read a text file - replace the charset with the one you need.

```
try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Once you have the individual lines, you can split them by whitespace: `str.split("\\s+");`

You get an array with three entries. I guess you can figure out the rest.